# Android live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have a sequence of imagaes of an animated wallpaper (150 png file).

I tried to generate an apk file with custom Livewallpaper2.6 but I don't find the generated apk file.

I want to how can I build this live wallpaper with my image sequence.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: How did you generate the apk?

Comment: @slayton I use costume LiveWallpaper: I put the number of the .png files, the app name, the description and the package name

Answer (score 0):

It should build the apk file in your `project\bin` folder have you tried searching your source folder for all .apk files? Something like the following perhaps:

```
my_android_project\bin\my_android_project.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

EdChum is right, but if you want to have an `apk` fie and install it on any device you want, you should sign it. In eclipse, right click on desired project and follow `android tools -> export signed app`.